# PHP $_POST empty on remote submission

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

If I post data to a test script on my web server (from a remote source) the $_POST array is empty but HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA has the posted information.

Data posted locally with a form works fine.

The server is Ubuntu 12.04/Apache/PHP 5.3.10, its a standard build.

**UPDATE**

Im using this to test the endpoint https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/

This is the REST server I am implementing https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver. Its been installed on a standard LAMP stack, and a fresh codeigniter install.

There are no redirects happening.

Comment: Are you using an html form ? If yes can you add the html code of the fom to your question ? And if not, then $_POST will only be populated if the sent data conform to a known encoding (as a PHP says; "[With a known encoding we decode it and populate $_POST](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31417)")

Comment: I've updated my question with some more information

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not getting some kind of redirection?  For example, you send post data to http://somedomain.com and it auto redirects you to https://somedomain.com or http://www.somedomain.com...  You will lose your post data that way.

Answer (score 1):

**1**. $_POST contains URL encoded (application/www-url-encoded) variables that are posted to your script and PHP decodes them for you. You use this one when you deal with HTML FORM data.

**2**. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA - gets the raw POST data and you need to use this when you write APIs and need XML/JSON/... input that cannot be decoded to $_POST by PHP.